# Android CM9/AOKP ThemeChooser Eclipse Sample? Where can I find it?

Tags: android, themes, cyanogenmod

I want to make a CM9/AOKP ThemeChooser Theme but I don't know how to start to create it.

Is there a working Ecplipse Project?

Where can I find it?

Many Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post by Ricardo Cerqueira featuring a CM9 theme template: https://plus.google.com/115049428938715274412/posts/Epq3Xt83Bpd

There's some complications when building a theme compared to a normal app which he describes in the README file. So with regard to using Eclipse, I'm sure you could use it as an editor but it may take some extensive tinkering if you'd like it to compile as well.